# Use a 3rd party object as a Core Data Entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am wanting to pull down and cache notes, notebooks and tags from the Evernote service using their iOS SDK. Their SDK comes with a `Store` that returns an array of model objects matching a filtered criteria I set.

I want to take those models and use them as a Entity in Core Data. I understand that I can't, because they inherit from NSObject. So my question to all of you is what are the best practices I can employe when I model my entities based on the Evernote model objects? It is a real pain because every time they change something, I have to reflect the same changes in my entities. Is there a work around, or am I stuck building a bridge (so to speak)?.

Thanks,
Johnathon

Comment: I don't understand your question here. Just kick off a data import each time models are returned form Evernote. Each model should be designed through a Core Data entity.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by importing. Bring down the objects from Evernote then manually assign their object properties to my entities? That will be a pain but is an option. There's a lot if properties to copy.

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment

> I don't understand your question here. Just kick off a data import
>   each time models are returned from Evernote. Each model should be
>   designed through a Core Data entity.

and you reply on it.

> Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by importing. Bring down the objects
>   from Evernote then manually assign their object properties to my
>   entities? That will be a pain but is an option. There's a lot if
>   properties to copy.

With *importing* I mean that you should insert a managed object for each model returned from the results received data from Evernote.

This means that if Evernote returns a model that contains three properties, you shoul create an `Entity` that looks the same (or similar since it strictly depends on what you UI will be).

Here I suppose that you Core Data store is a cache. So you should apply synchronization stuff. Items should be inserted, updated or removed based on user. Synchronization is not easy to achieve but I can suggest you the following tutorials.

- [How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service – Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1)
- [How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service – Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2)

You could also take advantage of RestKit in this case, since it offers an integration with Core Data. In particular, it allows to maps `NSObject`s, for example returned from a JSON call, to a Core Data entity in a easy way. An example can be found at [NSScrencast GitHub Repository](https://github.com/subdigital/nsscreencast/tree/master/051-intro-to-restkit-mapping/BeerInfo). Note that I don't know how Evernote SDK works. So, this approach could not be useful.

But if you are new to RestKit and Core Data, I really suggest to stick with plain Core Data. It's already difficult as its own.

If you need something else let me know.

**Update 1**

> I am going to be doing a synchronization for sure, so I assume I have
>   to map the Evernote object completely with a Managed Object. Since the
>   Evernote objects can contain data blobs representing video, pictures,
>   files etc, I will need to look at how to store that data in Core Data
>   as well.

In Core Data you need (this not a **must** but I really good advice) to store files (e.g. images) in the file system. Within an entity you should maintain only meta-informations (i.e. the path) of an image and through it retrieve the image later. This is not necessary for small data, but I think your binaries will be big in size.

Starting from iOS 5 there is a new flag called **External Storage** that do this for you based on heuristic algorithm.

> If you specify that the value of a managed object attribute may be
>   stored as an external record, Core Data heuristically decides on a
>   per-value basis whether it should save the data directly in the
>   database or store a URI to a separate file that it manages for you.

About searching for binary file I really suggest to an attribute called, for example, `tag`. This will allow you to search images, videos, etc. Obviously when you save you need to associate that tag with the specified binary data. This is just an idea.

P.S. If you need further support I really suggest to open a new question on SO. This to have a self-contained question.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am going to spend this evening reviewing all of the links. I am going to be doing a synchronization for sure, so I assume I have to map the Evernote object completely with a Managed Object. Since the Evernote objects can contain data blobs representing video, pictures, files etc, I will need to look at how to store that data in Core Data as well.

Comment: I am sure I will be asking questions as I review this stuff

Comment: You're welcome. @JohnathonSullinger Have a look to my edit. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the **External Storage** flag tip. I was pondering if I needed to store files externally but wasn't sure. If I need additional help I'll be sure to start a new question!

Answer (score -1):

You probably wanna save the object as `NSData`. Since I don't know what object you're looking for to use, I can't really tell if it's suitable for this. To see if it is, you would have to check if the class adopts the `NSCoding` protocol.

More info on archiving could be found in Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html

Comment: Saving the entire object as a single NSData blob makes it impossible to access single attributes, search for properties, use relationships etc. In other words, you don't have anything of what Core Data stands for.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what kind of objects it are, but I can imagine that you in fact want to save it as `NSData`. That's perfectly fine by what Core Data stands for. As far as I can see, he's trying to save a whole object, not it properties.

Comment: I am wanting to cache the object for local usage. Unfortunately storing the entire object as a NSData would not work because the cache could be several Gigabytes. In order to make it searchable I'd have to hold everything in memory because I can't search core Data for NSData objects with specific values etc.